# Telerik RadGrid Custom Aggregate - Unwanted Text

Tags: telerik, radgrid

When using a Telerik RadGrid with a custom aggregate, I'm trying to display a simple string in the footer row, such as "Total".  However, the RadGrid seems to automatically insert text for me at the beginning of the string, making it say "Custom: Total".  How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 5):

Found it.  You just have to set the DataFormatString property of the GridBoundColumn like so:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Capacity" UniqueName="CapacityType" DataField="CapacityType" ItemStyle-Width="210" ReadOnly="true" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:g}" Aggregate="Custom" />
```